# Windows task scheduler with regular user

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I have a powershell script on my network share (\server\dir\my.ps1).

- if I run this from command prompt (powershell -file "\server\dir\my.ps1") than work as expected.
- if I create a basic task in the scheduler with "Run Only When user logged on" than works as expected.
- **if check the "Run Whether user is logged on or not" then script won't run**
- in the action tab:Progam/Script --> powershell; Arguments:-file "\server\dir\my.ps1"
- in the task history I see the task run well ...but the script does nothing...
- the user is a regular user
- If I change the user to administrator than everything work as expected....

**Is it possible to run scheduled task with regular user with "run whether user is logged on or not"?**

#

**So i made some test:**

In the PS file i put this script:

> Test-Connection -ComputerName SBS | out-file "c:\script\test.txt"
>   $olSession = (New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application).Session
>   $olSession.Logon('Outlook') $contactsFolder = 10 $elemek =
>   $olSession.GetDefaultFolder($contactsFolder).Items
>   @($elemek)|ForEach-Object {$_.Delete()}

- The first line run as expected (with user logged on or not )
- The rest of line did not run
- If i paste this lines to cmd than everything run as expected
- If i change the settings to  "Run only if user logged in" than every line run as expected
- If i give admin rights to user the everything run as expected in logged off too...

So something with my outlook session lines...i don't understand...

Comment: Does the user have "Log on as batch job" rights?

Comment: Yes. In domain policy i granted right for the user. (before i made this settings, i can't save the task9

Comment: Try specifying the full path to the executable "c:\windows\system32\windowspowershel\1.0\powershell.exe", rather than just "powershell". You may not get a full environment when running a task while logged off, in which case the PATH variable won't be able to help find powershell.

Comment: nope...i edited my post with a short test...please if you could take a look at....thx

Comment: Oh, I have a feeling that because there is no desktop to launch on, the session doesn't get created. Try something like if ($olSession) { <do the script as normal> } else { "Variable not initialized" | Out-File "c:\script\VarNotInit.txt" }

Comment: Ok. Variable not initialized....but i don't understand..If i grant admin right to user than its ok?! So "dekstop launch" only if admin right? Any idea? Tnx